# Change appearance of citation reference eg. [4] to [ 4 ]

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am looking for way to change the appearance of the usual bracketed numbers to a bit more spacious style like this. But it seems like a hard thing to do. Could anyone help me?

[image]

I am using biblatex for the bibliography and put the references in the file bib.bib like this

```
@book{IEC60076-10,
author = "\textbf{IEC 60076-10:2016 }\text{Power transformers - Part 10: Determination of sound levels.}\newline Website: \url{https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/62880}"
}
```

Comment: why are you entring the title and url in the author field???? (it doesn't affect the specific question but it gives biblatex no chance of producing the intended layout)

Comment: which citation style are you using?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just because it produces the look I'm after. The references are techical standards (IEC) and I only want the technical name and the official source destination so that the reader can find it. There is no author or more correctly hundreds of them

Comment: @moewe bibencoding=ascii, style=numeric, sorting=none

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way that only changes the citation and bibliography labels.

We need to change the relevant cite commands as well as `labelnumberwidth`. The spaces used here are unbreakable thin spaces (`\,`), of course you can substitute them for anything else.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\mkbibspacedbrackets}[1]{\mkbibbrackets{\,#1\,}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibspacedbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibspacedbrackets{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibspacedbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibspacedbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Numbers in spaced brackets.]

A more radical solution would be the following redefinition

```
\renewrobustcmd{\mkbibbrackets}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \bibopenbracket\,#1\,\bibclosebracket
  \endgroup}
```

which would affect all brackets typeset with `\mkbibbrackets`.